# Code Compiling on Runtime as part of program

Tags: c#

This code snippet was written to compile the code at run-time.
The compiled code works like any other program.
Reflection can be accessed with.
I want to do a little different things.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "foo.exe", true);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
        @"using System.Linq;
            class Program {
              public static void Main(string[] args) {
                var q = from i in Enumerable.Range(1,100)
                          where i % 2 == 0
                          select i;
              }
            }");
        results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
    }
}
```

For Example :

My Code is  Textbox1.Text="123"; it is in a file or in database.

There is a form.A Textbox in form.
I want to use string code as part of my program on runtime.

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to do? It's not clear what the code snippet has to do with your problem.

Comment: May be he wants to write something like: `var Textbox1 = ..; Execute("Textbox1.Text='123'"); `. I.e. he wants to execute some code using context of the running code.

Comment: Is all your code just stuff like `textbox.Text = "..."`? Perhaps you would find it easier if you just stored a set of key/value pairs in a file somewhere (i.e. "Textbox1.Text", "123"). This sounds like you're trying to implement [application localisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5839we2z.aspx)... Perhaps you should be looking at [resx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) files.

Comment: @VorobeY1326 I wanto to Execute("Textbox1.Text='123'"); unless reflection

Comment: @Simon McKenzie,@VorobeY1326

I have a string like this.Text="sda"; or this.Backcolor=Color.Red or BindingSource source=new BindingSource(); Actually ı wanna add code to project from database on runtime and access the form all components controls ets.

Comment: Roslyn or Mono C# can help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx and http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler. You'd better use the latter, as the former is still in CTP and could not be used in production code.

Answer (score -1):

To do this, you can change the function name to string_Function instead of Main. Save the above code snippet as .cs file. Say Code_Snippet.cs. Now add this file to your MainProject. Wherever you want to use this code snippet you have to write line of code e.g. Code_Snippet.String_Function(TextBox.Text);

Comment: I have a string like this.Text="sda"; or this.Backcolor=Color.Red or BindingSource source=new BindingSource();
Actually ı wanna add code to project from database on runtime and access the form all components controls ets..